# Why Biginteger return non prime number and why less bits

Tags: java, biginteger, prime-factoring

I am a bit confused. I am trying to make a simple math equation with `BigInteger` with no success. I have 3 prime numbers in 256 bit and I tested it like below. My problem is that when I do the the math (a^b mod p) I got a non-prime number and also I got sometimes a `BigInteger` with 256 or 255 bits. Why does this happen and how do I avoid it?

```
Random r = new Random();

byte[] random = new byte[32];
r.nextBytes(random);
randomServerPrimeNumber = BigInteger.probablePrime(256, r);
//System.out.println(randomServerPrimeNumber.isProbablePrime(1));
//System.out.println(value.isProbablePrime(0));
//System.out.println(randomServerPrimeNumber.bitLength());

BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(Properties.exponent);
BigInteger mod = new BigInteger(Properties.modulus);
BigInteger result = exponent.modPow(randomServerPrimeNumber, mod);

System.out.println(exponent.isProbablePrime(1));//true
System.out.println(randomServerPrimeNumber.isProbablePrime(1));//true
System.out.println(mod.isProbablePrime(1));//true
System.out.println("");

System.out.println(exponent.bitLength());//256
System.out.println(randomServerPrimeNumber.bitLength());//256
System.out.println(mod.bitLength());//256

System.out.println("");
System.out.println(result.isProbablePrime(1));//false all time
System.out.println(result.bitLength());//sometime 256,255,242
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you accidentally switched the parameters in `exponent.modPow(randomServerPriemNumber, mod)`. a.modPow(b, c) evaluates to `a^b mod c`, not `b^a mod c`, but that shouldn't affect the result much, as all three numbers are 256bit length primes. As for the different bit lengths of the result, since the big length of BigInteger is the absolute minimum number of bits you would need to represent it, it differs for different values, even if they are modulo the same number.

Take, e.g. "10 mod 10" and "7 mod 10". The first evaluates to 0, with a bit length of 0. The second evaluates to 7, with a bit length 3.

As for whether a^b mod c should or should not be prime, please forgive my ignorance, but I am not aware that it should be one or the other. I am by no means knowledgeable concerning prime numbers, so someone else has to comment on that.

Comment: IIRC, per definition, 0 has a bitlength of 1.

Comment: I would have thought so, too. After all, it's illogical to represent a number with zero bits. But lo and behold, it's actually zero. I double checked (with Java 8).

Comment: OK, then I perhaps confused it with `BigInteger`. This should return 1, IIRC.